# ember-cli cleanup error when building

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I had [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) installed on my computer and my app was running perfectly, but yesterday I formatted my computer and upgraded to windows 10 and tried to install [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) exactly the same way it was before but now when I try to build or run my application I get this error:

```
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v4.2.1. Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
version: 1.13.8
Cleanup error.
ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-output_path-jfPUvJvW.tmp'
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-output_path-jfPUvJvW.tmp'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:763:18)
    at rmkidsSync (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:247:11)
    at rmdirSync (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:237:7)
    at fixWinEPERMSync (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:150:5)
    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:216:26)
    at Object.remove (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\node_modules\quick-temp\index.js:26:12)
    at ReadCompat.cleanup (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:69:13)
    at ConcatWithMaps.Plugin.cleanup (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:113:49)
    at cleanupTree (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli\lib\builder.js:147:17)
Build failed.
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-QzODcQgu.tmp\0\C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-QzODcQgu.tmp\0\ember-basic-dropdown\components\basic-dropdown.js'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-QzODcQgu.tmp\0\C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-QzODcQgu.tmp\0\ember-basic-dropdown\components\basic-dropdown.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at SourceMap.addFile (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\fast-sourcemap-concat\lib\source-map.js:68:19)
    at ConcatWithMaps.<anonymous> (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\concat-with-maps.js:96:17)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ConcatWithMaps.addFiles (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\concat-with-maps.js:93:9)
    at ConcatWithMaps.build (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\concat-with-maps.js:65:8)
    at C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Software\company\product\client-side\product2\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:493:16)
```

- node v4.2.1
- npm v2.14.7

But I've tried with others versions and the problem persisted.

The same application is working perfectly on another computer which also has windows 10 and the same node and npm versions.

If you need any extra information leave a comment and I'll edit the question.

Comment: Which version of Node and NPM are you using? And have you tried fully deleting the `tmp` folder?

Comment: Yes @JustinNiessner, I´ve tried it but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Try upgrading your npm version via `npm install -g npm` first. I wonder if you're hitting the Windows long file name limit.

Comment: It's entirely possible that I'm hitting the limit.

Comment: I've upgraded my npm versions and tried changing the applications folder and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today. It seems there's a bug in a dependency module:

```
"name": "fast-sourcemap-concat",
"version": "0.2.6"
```

it does not handle properly Windows paths starting with drive letters, like `C:/`.

For now, I fixed it manually in `fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js`, function `_resolveFile`, line 55, changing:

```
if (this.baseDir && filename.slice(0,1) !== '/') {
```

to:

```
if (this.baseDir && filename.slice(0,1) !== '/' && filename.slice(1,3) !== ':/') {
```

Seems to fix the issue for me.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to freeze dependencies so my build doesn't suddenly break?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5055

You will need to reinstall your node modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Ember CLI in your project directory (local version). You can follow the steps from [Ember CLI GitHub releases page](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases) - start with `rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp` and continue following **Project Update** guide.

Comment: Ok, so from my experience - make sure exactly all dependencies from package.json and bower.json match the ones from https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-output/commit/db09559dc922eafdfb6723969b53dfff1a8f5331.